# Why sphinx does not return attributes name?

Tags: sphinx

I use two indexes for search in Sphinx:

```
#users
source users : lsParentSource
{

    sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idDetailToUsers), MAX(idDetailToUsers) FROM detailtousers
    sql_query         = SELECT idDetailToUsers as id, 1000 as type, UsersTypeAccount, idDetailToUsers, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country FROM detailtousers join users ON users.idUsers = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join usersspecialization ON usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdUser = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join specializationtousers ON specializationtousers.idSpecialization = usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdSpecialization WHERE idDetailToUsers >= $start AND idDetailToUsers <= $end GROUP BY idDetailToUsers

    sql_attr_uint     = type
    sql_attr_uint     = idDetailToUsers
    sql_attr_uint     = UsersTypeAccount
    sql_field_string  = SpecializationName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersPhoto
    sql_attr_uint     = city
    sql_attr_uint     = country

    sql_query_info    = SELECT idDetailToUsers, DetailToUsersName, UsersTypeAccount, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country \
                        FROM detailtousers WHERE idDetailToUsers = $id
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}


#medical
source medical : lsParentSource
{

    sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idMedicalFacilities), MAX(idMedicalFacilities) FROM medicalfacilities
    sql_query         = SELECT idMedicalFacilities as id, 2000 as type, idMedicalFacilities, MedicalFacilitiesName, MedicalFacilitiesPhoto, city, country FROM medicalfacilities WHERE idMedicalFacilities >= $start AND idMedicalFacilities <= $end

    sql_attr_uint     = type
    sql_attr_uint     = MedicalFacilitiesIdUser
    sql_attr_uint     = idMedicalFacilities
    sql_field_string  = MedicalFacilitiesName
    sql_field_string  = MedicalFacilitiesPhoto
    sql_attr_uint     = city
    sql_attr_uint     = country

    sql_query_info    = SELECT MedicalFacilitiesIdUser, MedicalFacilitiesName, MedicalFacilitiesPhoto FROM medicalfacilities WHERE idMedicalFacilities = $id
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}
```

If use an index `users` only it returns me all attributes specified in select query.
But if use a two indexes the sphinx does not return attributes.
What is reason?

Result for index `users`:

```
array(1) {
  [533]=>
  array(2) {
    ["weight"]=>
    int(1)
    ["attrs"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Result for index `medical`:

```
array(5) {
  [451]=>
  array(2) {
    ["weight"]=>
    int(2)
    ["attrs"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [444]=>
  array(2) {
    ["weight"]=>
    int(1)
    ["attrs"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx only returns attributes common to the indexes in the query. you have different names.

You might be able to use the EXISTS function from sphinxQL in the SetSelect, but never tried.

Easiest is just to use the same attribute names.

Comment: But when I use one index in sphinx.conf it returns me attributes with a names and values, For what attributes then?

Comment: Also it must return me at least one attribute with a table name

Comment: You might be able to use `->setSelect('type');` for that but not sure. Sphinx really expects multi-index queries to use the same schema.

Comment: I will try, so for each index I must do separate query to table?

Comment: If you want to have different attributes yes. Think like mysql UNION - each row in the result must have the same columns.